# Search and replace in text file

Tags: c++, search, replace, fstream

I'm trying to search and replace in a text file but it isn't working, I know its simple feel like im missing something small. I'm trying to replace Electric with a non-space character. Can anyone help me out?

Thanks

```
#include <string>

#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std; 

    int main() {

    string line; 
    ifstream myfile("test.txt");
    if (!myfile.is_open())
    {
        cout << "cant open";
        return 1;
    }
    ofstream myfile2("outfile.txt");

    std::string str("");
    std::string str2("Electric");
    while (getline(myfile, line))
    {
        std::size_t found = str.find(str2);

        found = str.find("Electric");
        if (found != std::string::npos) {
            str.replace(str.find(str2), str2.length(), "");
            myfile2 << found << "\n";
            //std::cout << line << "\n";
        }

        //myfile2 << str2 << "\n";
    }
        remove("test.txt");
        rename("outfile.txt", "test.txt");
        return 0; 
}
```

Comment: What (how) isn't (it) working?

Comment: For example I have a full paragraph in a text file I created, but I want to just remove the string "Electric" from it and replace it with an empty space character. But literally nothing happens when I run the program to the text file. @BjarneStroustrup

Comment: Are you trying to modify the file?

Comment: Could you point the line where you're modifying it?

Comment: str.replace(str.find(str2), str2.length(), ""); .. Isn't that modifying it to replace the word Electric with "" ? @ZDF

Comment: I see strings, but no streams.

Comment: You simply don't write to any file

Comment: Oh! I just realized I wasn't, although when I updated it same thing nothing happens. I edited it in the main post.  @DimChtz

Comment: I updated it, but same thing ! :( @ZDF

Comment: You read the file into `line`, not `str`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
int main()
{
  using namespace std;

  ifstream is( "in.txt" );
  if ( !is )
    return -1;

  ofstream os( "out.txt" );
  if ( !os )
    return -2;

  string f = "Electric";
  string r = "";

  string s;
  while ( getline( is, s ) ) // read from is
  {
    // replace one:
    //std::size_t p = s.find( f );
    //if ( p != std::string::npos )
    //  s.replace( p, f.length(), "" );

    // replace all:
    for ( size_t p = s.find( f ); p != string::npos; p = s.find( f, p ) )
      s.replace( p, f.length(), r );

    os << s << endl; // write to os
  }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I really appreciate it. I don't know if its just me not understanding but I ended up replacing it with what you did and put my code into what you created but still not working. @ZDF

Comment: See the updated answer. I just cleaned and copied your code. Note that your code removes only one appearance per line.

Comment: See the updated answer. I have added code for _replace all_.

Answer (score 1):

A crude solution:

```
#ifndef _STREAMBUF_H
#include <streambuf>
#endif


void ReplaceInFile(string inputfile, string outputfile, string replace_what, string replace_with) {

   //Read file into string
    ifstream ifs(inputfile);
    string inputtext((istreambuf_iterator<char>(ifs)),
        istreambuf_iterator<char>());
    ifs.close();


    //Replace string
    size_t replace_count = 0;
    size_t found = !string::npos /*not npos*/;
    while (!(found == string::npos)) {
        found = inputtext.find(replace_what, found);
        if (found != string::npos) {
            ++replace_count;
            inputtext.replace(found, replace_what.length(), replace_with);
        }
    }

    //Output how many replacements were made
    cout << "Replaced " << replace_count, (replace_count == 1) ? cout << " word.\n" : cout << " words.\n";

    //Update file
    ofstream ofs(outputfile /*,ios::trunc*/); //ios::trunc with clear file first, else use ios::app, to append!!
    ofs << inputtext; //output now-updated string
    ofs.close();
}
```

Example use:

```
ReplaceInFile("tester.txt", "updated.txt", "foo", "bar");
```